# The convex hull of a manifold whose cobordism class is trivial

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact orientable  $n$ dimensional  manifold. Assume that $M$ has trivial cobordism class. 
Is there an embedding  of $M$ in some Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that the  convex hull of $M$ is a $n+1$ dimensional manifold whose boundary is $M$?

Here the image  of  $M$ under the   embedding is denoted again by $M$.

**Note:** One can pose the same question in the following geometric manner:

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with trivial cobordism class. Is  there an isometric embedding of  $M$ in some Euclidean space such that the convex hull of  $M$ is  a manifold whose boundary is $M$?

Comment: Generally no.  For example, plenty of homotopy spheres do not bound contractible manifolds.   Many (?most?) homology 3-spheres do not bound contractible 4-manifolds, yet all 3-manifolds are null cobordant.

Comment: @RyanBudney Snap!

Comment: @RyanBudney I think Freedman proved that every homology 3-sphere bounds a contractible topological 4-manifold.

Comment: @Zerox, I doubt it, but if you can find such a claim somewhere, you will have found a contradiction.  For example, the Poincare Dodecahedral Space does not bound a contractible 4-manifold, due to the Rochlin invariant.

Comment: @RyanBudney I think you missed the word topological in Zerox's comment. On the other hand, the original question is a bit ambiguous about the category one is working in. The first part could be in the smooth/PL/topological category, and might have different answers. The second part presumably refers to smooth manifolds (because of the Riemannian metric).

Comment: @DannyRuberman: Thanks, yes I missed that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are exotic spheres (which are null cobordant) which do not bound a parallelisable manifold. Since the convex hull is contractible, it would be parallelisable if it were a manifold, so these guys do not admit embeddings like you want.

Answer (score 12):

Implicit in the other responses is the fact that if $M$ bounds a convex manifold $W$, then $W$ is contractible and so M has the homology of a sphere. So any null-cobordant manifold that is not a homology sphere is a counterexample. Eg take $M = X \# -X$ where $X$ is any orientable manifold with non-trivial homology.